# Can't increase resolution on HP laptop webcam

Tags: windows-10, webcam

I've just bought an HP 255 G6 laptop (1WY96EA), and the webcam resolution (according to the Windows 10 Camera app) is 640x360. The spec says it's an HD camera, though. I've installed all the Windows updates and all the HP updates, but it hasn't helped. What else can I try?

Comment: According to this: https://support.hp.com/ph-en/document/c05478271 the webcam itself only supports up to 460p. The HD resolution (720p) is for when you take still photo's using the HD Camera app. Although it should at least support 460p for the webcam in the windows 10 camera app, its not going to go higher than that. That said, an internet search reveals others with the same problem.

Comment: @LPChip That page says "720p by 30 frames per second". Any ideas what I could try to improve it?

Comment: Took another look at that page. I'm now wondering given that the page has other conflicting items as well, if it lists all specifications for different models combined, which would mean that you would need a different model for the 720p camera. Other than that, I have no idea how to get a higher resolution on the camera, but you may need to install a driver for that.